# How to Get Sales Order Report Collection Programmatically in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order, reports

I want to get sales order report collection programmatically. I don't know by which class I can able to fetch. Can anyone please help me?

I want to get same records which display in screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the data you want by using the collection:

*`vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/ResourceModel/Report/Order/Collection.php`*

Magento is implementing the grid in your screenshot in this file:

*`vendor/magento/module-reports/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Sales/Grid.php`*

where you should be able to get examples on how to implement it (with filters).

Comment: Can you please add full code?